# Async debugging problem with node and vs code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, babeljs

My breakpoints in VS code keep jumping - I am using node.JS and when I run the debugger my breakpoint goes from line 30 approximately to line 130 or so at the bottom of the file with the export function.

The project I am working on is a service layer so it is pretty much all async.

```
    async superspecficfunnamedoeshere(blah, accessToken) {
        console.log('example') 
Breakpoint goes on above line^
    Bunch more code goes here, here is the function etc , the breakpoint is just under the function declaration 
        }
    }

export thing from thing
^^ breakpoint moves to bottom export statement.
```

Putting a breakpoint in this console.log line just completely skips the entire function and goes to the export statement at the bottom.

Here is my launch.json- at first it was failing at the import statement until I configured it to work with babel:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "thing1",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app.js",
      "protocol": "inspector",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--harmony",
            ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
      "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
      "outFiles": [ "${workspaceFolder}/bin/**/*.js" ],
    }
  ]
}
```

lastly here is my babel config

```
{ "env": {
    "development": {
    "sourceMaps": true,
    "retainLines": true
    }
    },
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "node": "current"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

How can I get debugging async functions to work?

I've already tried going through the vs code docs, and I'm a little confused on how source maps work. But I have implemented some of the suggestions there.

There is no error message just the breakpoint moving to the end of the file from the console.log line where the breakpoint is much earlier (without anything to show for it)

Comment: Am I missreading your source or are you trying to assign values to the numerical value 1?  That's what `const {1} = a` means to me.

Comment: That stuff is just a placeholder to illustrate my issue , you can ignore the first bit of code cause really the whole point was to say my breakpoint was set to my console.log but it moves when I hit 'play' and greys out the original location.